# How can I add a custom action to the Ribbon in the Site Pages Page Actions group in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, ribbon, custom-action, sitepages

I'm trying to create a Ribbon custom action for SharePoint 2013 in Site Pages ->Page->Page Actions. Of successfully manage to create one for Documents->Files->Manage with Visual Studio features but I don't know if I can do the same in this case or if I just have to add the code myself to get what I want.

Any help would be great thanks. :)

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, no. I checked for the link and copied in Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PubPageActions.Controls._children unfortunately I can't see where it was added. Maybe I don't have the right address. And why is it called WikiPageTab?

Answer (score 2):

I was originally going to suggest this location:

`Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PageActions`

But i did a quick search and this guy's blog has more detailed information.

http://sanderschutten.blogspot.com/2010/05/adding-buttons-to-mss2010-ribbon.html

Comment: I followed the link but it doesn't work for me. Instead I used Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PageActions.Controls._children which seems to work. However it is not enabled unless there are selected files.